# Why is Gradient Accumulation not used frequently in training large models compared to using bigger batch sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, modeling, gradient-descent, backpropagation

So I was currently going through various implementations of models and they set a large batch size of around 256 , running this is google collab is very memory intensive, so I decided to use a batch size of 4 with a gradient accumulate of 64 which theoretically should achieve the same performance, but I don't understand why this is not used as a standard , is there some inherent disadvantage of using gradient accumulate ?

If not then I don't understand the reason , repositories of deep learning projects from Google and Facebook use large batch sizes and not gradient accumulate.

Comment: Sure, if you don't have the budget to buy more RAM, then you can make the problem small enough to fit into the RAM that you have already. But using a batch size of 4 in place of a batch size of 256 implies that you're computing 16 times as many iterations. How much time does that take? Does it compare favorably to how long it takes to run the same model with batch size 256?

Comment: hmm.. makes sense, Is there any comparative article or papers that address that , I couldn't find it and currently test it out , I think using more workers in data loader could be one way of increasing the speed to load the batch data faster, couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: Sure, increasing parallelism can speed things up, but you can apply the same strategy to the model that uses a batch size of 256, so that's not really an advantage that's unique to your proposal. You'll have to compare the runtime of your proposal to the runtime of the large batch method.

Comment: When I tested it out internally for a batch size of 64 vs grad accumulate of 4 with batch size of 16 there was a speed of 20 seconds , so overall felt no difference , I think further analysis is required to test out different scenarios. Maybe for higher batch sizes there is a significant improvement of speed .